# How to Launch an android app from other app and give it a file name, so launched app open this file and do its default view operation?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an android app and I want to launch another app within my app. I know that I can get intent and run the desired app by following procedure:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("pacage_name");
startActivity(intent);
```

But how we can include a parameter, for example a file name, which app can open and operate on it.

Suppose we don’t know the structure of app’s activities. It can be any standard android app (such as gallery). We know that it can get a parameter and operate on it.

In general, how android system launch an app and pass it a file name to operate on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intent.putExtra` to pass on any kind of information to other activities.

Such as in your example, where we can do this:

```
String yourInformation = "SomeInformation";

Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("pacage_name");
intent.putExtra("MY_INTENT_TAG", yourInformation);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the `Activity` you are going to (i.e. where the user will end up), you do this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String receivedInfo = extras.getString("MY_INTENT_TAG");
```

You can also read more about starting activities using `Intent`s [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), and read more about the `Intent` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Thank’s for the answer. I am familiar with putExtra and getExtra. Bu these two can only be useful when you know the INTENT_TAG. Let me put my question another way. I have a graphic file (for example file.jpg) which is stored somewhere on the Filesystem. How can I open this file with gallery (or any other known app) in my application? Suppose app package name is com.package.name.

Answer (score 0):

I found some how to do this:

```
Intent viewDoc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewDoc.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("file_path")),"mimeType");
viewDoc.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.name","com.package.name.DesiredActivity"));

startActivity(viewDoc);
```